# Proving that length of closed intervals in fat Cantor Set approaches 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, cantor-set

I am looking to show that $l_n$ where $l_n$ denotes the length of closed subintervals in the nth stage of the fat cantor set approaches 0. I define the fat cantor set $C_\alpha$ to be the set constructed by first deleting the intervals $(1/2 - \alpha/4, 1/2+\alpha/4)$ from $[0,1]$, then deleting intervals centered at the midpoint of the new closed intervals, and taking off $\alpha/8$ from each side, and so on and so forth. To show these lengths go to 0, I first outlined a recursive formula for $l_n$ given by:
$$
l_n = \frac{1}{2}\left( l_{n-1}-\frac{\alpha}{2^{n+1}}\right)
$$
It was easy to show the sequence was monotone decreasing, but now I must show that it has infimum 0. I am not entirely sure how to do this, as this recursive formula is annoying to work with. I was wonderign if anyone could lead me down the right path. Please note that this is a homework problem, so a hint would be preferable to a full answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Just ignore the complicated term with $\alpha$, and write your recurrence as $l_n\leq \frac{1}{2} l_{n-1}$.  What upper bound on $l_n$ does this give by induction?

More generally, when you want to prove things about limits, you just want *inequalities*.  So you should not worry about getting some exact formula you can work with; instead you just want simple estimates which you can prove are upper and lower bounds and are good enough for the final conclusion you want.